# Makefile for compiling each c source file into a Linux kernel module

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel

I have a directory full of c source files, each one could be compiled into a independent kernel module, the following Makefile doesn't work:

```
sources := $(wildcard *.c)
obj-m += $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(sources))

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

But if I use `obj-m += mod1.o mod2.o` this will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below snippet from makefile

```
obj-m += $(subst .c,.o, $(wildcard *.c))
```

`subst` will replace `.c` suffixes with `.o`

Answer (score 0):

try to use something like :

```
obj-m += $(sources:.c=.o)
```